Norm of the operator $T_n- T.$
Fo $n\in\mathbb N$, let $T_n :(l^1, \|.\|_{1})\to (l^{\infty}, \|.\|_{\infty})$
and $T :(l^1, \|.\|_{1})\to (l^{\infty}, \|.\|_{\infty})$ be the  the bounded linear operators defined by $T_n(x_1, x_2,\cdots)= (y_1,y_2,\cdots), ~\text{where} y_j=\begin{cases}
x_j & j\leq n\\
x_n & j>n
\end{cases}$
and $$T(x_1, x_2,\cdots)= (x_1, x_2, \cdots)$$
Then
$A.$ $\| T_n\|$ does not converge to $\|T\|$ as $n\to\infty$
$B$. $\| T_n -T\|$ converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$
$C.$ for all $x\in l^1, \| T_n(x) - T(x)\|$ converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$
I can handle options $A$ and $C$. I am having difficulty with the option $B.$
Analysis of $\|T_n - T\|$
$\|(T_n - T)(x)\| = \|(0, 0, \cdots, 0, x_n - x_{n+1}, x_n - x_{n+2}, \cdots)\|= sup_{j\geq n+1} |x_n- x_j| .$
Unable to find the norm of $\| T_n -T\|$. Please help. Thank you.

The norms of $T_n$ and $T$ are equal $1.$ The norm of $T_n-T$ is equal $1.$

$|T_n -T|\leq 2$

@RyszardSzwarc  how to find $| T_n -T| ?$

We have $|x_n-x_j|\le |x_n|+|x_j|\le \|x\|_1.$ Hence $\|T_n-T\|\le 1.$ On the other hand for $\delta_{n+1}$ we have $T\delta_{n+1}=\delta_{n+1}$ and $T_n\delta_{n+1}=0.$ Therefore $\|T_n-T\|\ge 1.$

Now got it. Thank you very much...

Please do not address me Sir.
